# Query with linq for balanced values of a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with several normalized doubles from 0 to 1.
The class at all has about 100.000 entries and looks like this:

```
class Data
{
    public double Norm1 { get; set; }
    public double Norm2 { get; set; }
    public double Norm3 { get; set; }
    public double Norm4 { get; set; }
}
```

The entries are added to a `<List>`.
Now I have to find the best balanced entry in this list.

At the moement I use a loop to find this best balanced value.
The loop looks like this:

```
double nor = 0.01;
List<Data> tempList = null;
List<Data> lasttempList = null;
do
{
    tempList = null;
    tempList = new List<Data>(DATALIST);
    tempList = tempList
                   .Select(i => i)
                   .Where(j => 
                       j.Norm1 >= nor 
                       && j.Norm2 >= nor 
                       && j.Norm3 >= nor 
                       && j.avgN >= nor 
                       && j.Norm4 >= nor
                   ).ToList();

    if (tempList.Count() > 0)
        lasttempList = new List<Data>(tempList);

    nor = nor + 0.01;

} while (tempList.Count() > 1 && nor <= 0.99);
```

At the end I am checking tempList or lasttempList for entries.

Has anyone an idea how to do this effort without a loop and just using Linq?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Please provide some example data and expected output

Comment: If you put unescaped stuff like `<List>` in ordinary text, browsers will interpret that as an unknown HTML tag and swallow it. Readers will see "The entries are added to a . Now I have to find..." and wonder what you're trying to say.

Comment: That loop is an excellent example of code that should be written as a loop. The only reason to kludge it into LINQ would be as a stunt, and in programming, stunts don't age well. I'd remove this line: `tempList = null;`, and replace `if (tempList.Count() > 0)` with `if (tempList.Any())` But there's no harm in what you've got.

Comment: Here is some data:
Here is some data:
            DATALIST.Add(new Data() { Nor1 = 0.557429718875502, Nor2 = 0.444986538304642, Nor3 = 0.113636363636363, Nor4 = 0.275212970596318 });
            DATALIST.Add(new Data() { Nor1 = 0.38152610441767, Nor2 = 0.373092926490985, Nor3 = 0.0454545454545455, Nor4 = 0.0369881835669139 });

I have to get the balanced best value. So it makes no sence to build a score. The best is only the enrie where all entries of the class are balanced at it's best.

Comment: I wonder if it could be faster if you did more of a binary search type pattern.  Starting by checking .5, and then if it passes check .75, and if it fails then check .25.  But you weren't asking about speed.

Comment: @RainerGrunert If you have anything to add to the question, please add it to the question. In a comment it's unreadable, if it's even noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i am on the right direction, but let me try. I will assume that:

1. `DATALIST` is the input which is consisted (not mutated) during the while cycle.
2. You expect that the best balanced value (satisfying the predicate) will be exactly 1.

We can compute a limit value for each `Data` in the list and create groups with the values of the same limit. This opens two scenarios for us.

1. We have exactly one group with single value.
2. We have several groups with exactly single values in each group.

Se first lets compute the limit. You check against .01, .02, .03 and so on.
So we can write something like this to compute the limit for an `Data`.

```
private static double ComputeLimit(Data data)
{
    // all of the original values from the data object
    // unified to two deciaml digits after the dot.
    var values = new [] { data.Norm1, data.Norm2, data.Norm3, data.Norm4, data.avgN }
       .Select(x => Math.Floor(x * 100) / 100); 

   // the limit it self can be represented as the smallest number in the array
   // if we need all of the values to be greater then some limit
   // we ca assume that the smallest number is actually the limit of the data object
   var limit = values.Min();

   return limit;
}
```

Now lets create the groups. Each group will contain all the numbers from a specific limit.

```
var groups = DATALIST.GroupBy(ComputeLimit);

// using .Skip(1).Any() instead of .Count() because it is faster
// to determ if the group has exactly one item
// NOTE: If there is more then one group having exactly one item
// the result will be the group with the lowest limit
// also the ordering may be OK for you, if you need to keep the result consisted
var bestBalanced = groups
         .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any() == false)
         .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
         .First()
         .Single()
```